# how to make android phone to be a socket server?

Tags: android, serversocket

I develop an socket server in android phone called "A". and deploy an socket client in another android phone called "B".

phone A act socket server.
phone B act socket client.
PC Server C act an socket server, receive phone "A" request with ip information.and send the ip of "A" to phone "B".

now, I has connected "B" to "A"  successfully in local area network. 
also,I want to connect "B" to "A" in 3G network.

first, I startup Socket Server C. and listen phone A and phone B.

second,start phone B, and connect to Server C. so the Server C can communicate with phone B each other  by the connected socket.

third,start phone A, and connect to Server C. so  the Server C can communicate with phone A each other by the connected socket.

though the first and second, phone B can communicate with phone A each other.

however,I want to speed the transfer between phone B and phone A, reduce the pressure on the server C. I just use PC Server C to send the phone A's ip to phone B.
then, phone B connect to phone A use the ip received from Server C.

fetch the ip:
for wifi network:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();  
int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
String ip = (ipAddress & 0xFF)+ "." + ((ipAddress >> 8 ) & 0xFF)+ "." + ((ipAddress >> 16 ) & 0xFF) +"."+((ipAddress >> 24 ) & 0xFF);
Log.d(TAG, " wifi net , ip: "+ip);
return ip;
```

for 3G network:

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
  NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
  for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
      InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
      if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
          String ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
          Log.d(TAG, " mobile net , ip: "+ip);
          return ip;
      }
  }
}
```

but success in network, and fail in 3G network.

I guess there maybe something about the network mechanisms.
Can you explain it as much as possible and provide any other solution to make the connection between two phone in 3G network? 
thanks so much.